# Scalaの型階層表示でサブクラスが表示されない

Tags: scala, eclipse

Eclipseにて、Scalaクラスを表示中にF4押下で「型階層」を表示することができますが、
この際、「型階層」ビューには継承関係の親クラスは表示されるのですが、
サブクラスが表示されません。

Javaクラスで同様の操作をした場合は親クラス、サブクラスともに表示されるのですが、
Scalaクラスでも同様に表示する方法はないでしょうか？

Eclipse Luna(4.4.2)
Eclipse Scala IDE(4.1.0)